# How to Restore SharePoint Site Backup Integrated with MS Dynamics CRM?

Tags: dynamics-crm, sharepoint-integration

We have a SharePoint 2013 Team site integrated with MS Dynamics CRM. We used listcomponent wsp for the integration. After integration with CRM some lists (Customer) are created in the SharePoint portal. Users are uploaded documents from CRM and share point into the Customer document library. Now we faced an issue while restoring  the lists in the new server. we saved the lists as template along with the data include option and created new document library with the same name (Customer) in the new server and integrated with CRM. Now after integration with CRM, again the lists are created with names (Customer1). All the data was present in the Customer Doc lib and all the new documents are coming into the Customer1 Doc lib. Can anyone suggest any approach for the issue?

Our requirement is to restore  old data to list and need to integrate the same list with CRM so that all the old data and new data should be in single list.